# Duplicates in an unix text file based on multiple fields

Tags: unix, duplicates

I have a requirement to find duplicates based on three columns in a `.txt` file in unix which is delimited by `,`.

Input:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,gf,h
a,bd,cg,dd,ey,f,g,h
a,b,df,d,e,fd,g,h
a,b,ck,d,eg,f,g,h
```

Let's take we are finding dupliactes based on 1,2,5 fields.

Expected output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,gf,h
a,b,df,d,e,fd,g,h
```

Can anyone help to write a script for this or is there a command already available?

I tried like this:

```
awk -F, '!x[$1,$2,$3]++' file.txt but did not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using awk:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { x[$1,$2,$5]++; next } x[$1,$2,$5] > 1' a.txt a.txt
```

This is simple, but reads the file two times. On the first pass (FNR==NR), it maintains counts based on key fields. During the second pass, if prints the line if its key was found more than once.

Another way using awk:

```
awk -F, '{if (x[$1$2$5]) { y[$1$2$5]++; print $0; if (y[$1$2$5] == 1) { print x[$1$2$5] } } x[$1$2$5] = $0}' a.txt
```

Explanation:

```
  1  awk -F, 

  2   '{if (x[$1$2$5]) 
  3        { y[$1$2$5]++; print $0;
  4         if (y[$1$2$5] == 1) 

  5            { print x[$1$2$5] } 

  6       } x[$1$2$5] = $0

  7    }'
```

Line 2: If x has $1$2$5, this key was seen before, do steps 3-5

Line 3: Increment the count and print the line because it is a dup

Line 4: This means, We are seeing this key for the 2nd time, so we need to print the first line with this key. Last time we saw this key we did not know whether it was a dup or not. So we print the first line in step 5.

Line 6: Store the current line against the key so we can use it in step 2

Another way using sort, uniq and awk

Note: uniq command has an option '-f' to skip the specified number of fields before it starts comparison.

sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2 -k5,5 a.txt | awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = " "} {print $0, $1, $2, $5}' | sed 's/,/ /g' | uniq -f7 -D | sed 's/ /,/g' | cut -d',' -f 1-7

This sorts based on fields 1,2,5. awk prints the original line and appends fields 1,2,5 . sed changes the delimiter because uniq does not have an option to specify delimiter. uniq skips first 7 fields and works on rest of the line and prints duplicate lines.

Comment: It worked!!!.. But its printing with spaces i.e like
___________________________
a,b,c,d,e,f,gf,h

a,b,df,d,e,fd,g,h

__________________________

Comment: Which of the above commands are you using? What is the version of awk? May be you need to explicitly put "\n" in the print statement

Comment: Another simple way and very fast:     awk '!x[$1,$2]++' FS="~" $srcfile > $tgtfile

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue 
I needed to eliminate duplicate detail records while preserving flat file record formatting and seqence of the records.
The duplication caused by a time expansion of the date field in column 2 of the detail only.
Receiving system was reporting duplication on columns 4 and 5.

I cobbled together this quick hack to resolve it.

First read the file data into an array
Then we  can read and manipulate the individual records (crudely with a counter) as demonstrated in this snippet integrating a case statement to logically treat the various record types.

Cheers!

readarray inrecs < [input file name]

filebase=`echo "[input file name] | cut -d '.' -f1`

i=1

for inrec in "${inrecs[@]}";do

field1=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f1`

field2=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f2`

field3=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f3`

field4=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f4`

field5=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f5`

field6=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f6`

field7=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f7`

field8=`echo ${inrecs[$i-1]} | cut -d',' -f8`

case $field1 in

```
'H')

  echo "$field1,$field2,$field3">${filebase}.new

;;
'D')

  dupecount=0

  dupecount=`zegrep -c -e "${field4},${field5}" ${infile}`

  if [[ "$dupecount" -gt 1 ]];then

    writtencount=0

    writtencount=`zegrep -c -e "${field4},${field5}" ${filebase}.new`

    if [[ "${writtencount}" -eq 0 ]];then

      echo "$field1,$field2,$field3,$field4,$field5,$field6,$field7,$field8,">>${filebase}.new
    fi  
  else
    echo "$field1,$field2,$field3,$field4,$field5,$field6,$field7,$field8,">>${filebase}.new 

  fi
;;
'T')
  dcount=`zegrep -c '^D' ${filebase}.new`
  echo "$field1,$field2,$dcount,$field4">>${filebase}.new
;;
```

esac

((i++))

done